# Snowflake object_construct unloading Key Order should be preserved as same. how to maintain the order not by alphabetical?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task, snowflake-pipe, snowflake-data-masking

I use copy command of snowflake which is below  returns a file with content json

copy into @elasticsearch/product/sf_index from (select object_construct(**'id',id, alpha,'alpha'**)from table limit 1)  file_format = (type = json, COMPRESSION=NONE), overwrite=TRUE, single = TRUE, max_file_size=5368709120;

the output in json file is

```
{ 
    "alpha":"alpha", 
    "id" :"1"
}
```

I want the **order to be preserved** here, **not order by alphabetical** ? like this

```
{
"id" :"1",
"alpha":"alpha",
}
```

any solutions??
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the need to have the attributes in any particular order?  Similar to your earlier post, these seem like odd requirements for a JSON document.

Comment: Thanks, This requirement is removed. just now.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be preserved the order if you force the data to be sorted to achieve this  create primary key constrain ([link](https://dwgeek.com/snowflake-primary-key-constraint-and-syntax.html/)) on id column and define as INT.

While loading data cast the id column as int (**[links](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/cast.html)** )

Comment: This would force the order of the records, but not the order of the attributes, which was the OP's question.